# trying to get data from array string that includes API address

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to get the data from an array that includes the API inside, the problem is the amount of api inside the array sometimes different with the others.

```
{
"name": "CR90 corvette", 
"model": "CR90 corvette", 
"manufacturer": "Corellian Engineering Corporation", 
"cost_in_credits": "3500000", 
"length": "150", 
"max_atmosphering_speed": "950", 
"crew": "30-165", 
"passengers": "600", 
"cargo_capacity": "3000000", 
"consumables": "1 year", 
"hyperdrive_rating": "2.0", 
"MGLT": "60", 
"starship_class": "corvette", 
"pilots": [], 
"films": [
    "http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
    "http://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
    "http://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
], 
"created": "2014-12-10T14:20:33.369000Z", 
"edited": "2014-12-20T21:23:49.867000Z", 
"url": "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/2/"}
```

In the json code above, **Films** field is the array that I means, for example in this data the **Films** has 3 data in the form of API addresses, in the other data, they have 2 data of API addresses and so on.

My question is how can I call the API inside the array like that, and how can I call the all API address inside at the same time?

Thank you for ur time to read this, kudos.

Comment: what do you mean by call ? You mean asynchronous call ?

Comment: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `async` `await` & then use `fetch` to make the api call.

```js
let data = {
  "name": "CR90 corvette",
  "model": "CR90 corvette",
  "manufacturer": "Corellian Engineering Corporation",
  "cost_in_credits": "3500000",
  "length": "150",
  "max_atmosphering_speed": "950",
  "crew": "30-165",
  "passengers": "600",
  "cargo_capacity": "3000000",
  "consumables": "1 year",
  "hyperdrive_rating": "2.0",
  "MGLT": "60",
  "starship_class": "corvette",
  "pilots": [],
  "films": [
    "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
    "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
    "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
  ],
  "created": "2014-12-10T14:20:33.369000Z",
  "edited": "2014-12-20T21:23:49.867000Z",
  "url": "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/2/"
};

async function fncGetResult(arr) {
  let val = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const res = await fetch(arr[i]).then(d => d.json()).then(d =>d);
    val.push(res)
  };
  return val;
}

fncGetResult(data.films).then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: This will make the requests sequentially, i think `promise.all` is far better option to use here because each HTTP request is independent of the other requests.

Comment: i just tried your code and it's working, but then i getting an error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): arr is undefined", how can i fix that?

Comment: @brk i put my full code here https://codeshare.io/starship

Comment: @brk some array that includes API addresses

Comment: Try by calling like this `axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/starships/${id}/`).then((result) => {
      setDetail(result.data);
      fncGetResult(result.data.films)
    });`

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of doing this. The following code sends off the requests for film data in rapid succession, and then uses [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for them all to return before proceeding. Note that `Promise.all` will fail-fast if one request throws an exception. Use [`Promise#allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) if you want to fail-slow.

```js
const data = { films: [ 'http://example.com/1', 'http://example.com/2', 'http://example.com/3' ]}
const { films: urls } = data
const promises = []

for(let url of urls)
  promises.push(fetch(url))

Promise.all(promises)
  .then((filmDetails) => {
    for(let details of filmDetails)
      console.log(filmDetails)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `map` from package [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map).

> Async is a utility module which provides straight-forward, powerful functions for working with asynchronous JavaScript. Although originally designed for use with Node.js and installable via npm i async, it can also be used directly in the browser.

First parameter is your **array**, which you can destruct from your object, second is call to your api or any other **asynchronous function** (I'm using `axios` package here, but you can call the api just with node native package `http`) and third is a **callback function** which can provide you check for successful operation.

```
import async from 'async'
import axios from 'axios'

const obj = {
    name: "CR90 corvette", 
    films: [    
        "http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",  
        "http://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
        "http://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
    ]
}

const { films } = obj

const responses = async.map(
    films, 
    (url, callback) => {
        try {
            axios.get(url)
            callback(null, 'OK')
        } catch (error) {
            callback(error)
        }
    }, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        console.log(result)
    }
)
```